# Trying to print a generator object with a short code

Tags: python-3.x

It probably has been asked before,
But I couldn't find something like that,
I'm trying to print a generator object:

```
n="12234451"
print(*[n[c]for c in range(len(n))if n[c]!=n[c-1]or c==0],sep="")
```

I usually use something like that, however, I'm wondering if it's the most efficient way to do it
(without changing the fact that the expression is in the print)
Thanks for your time

Comment: Is this for a code golf? If so you can consider asking the question on the code golf stack exchange. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Efficient by what standard? What are your requirements and why doesn't your code match them?